# How to convert a string into a Point?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of strings of the format "x,y". I would like to make them all into Points. The best Point constructor I can find takes two ints. What is the best way in C# to turn `"14,42"` into `new Point(14,42);`?

I know the Regex for doing that is `/(\d+),(\d+)/`, but I'm having a hard time turning those two match groups into ints in C#.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this:

```
string[] coords = str.Split(',');

Point point = new Point(int.Parse(coords[0]), int.Parse(coords[1]));
```

Comment: missing a parentheses after the first Parse, thats what you get for typing it in without checking in VS.

Answer (score 13):

There is `Point.Parse` (System.Windows.Point.Parse, WindowsBase.dll) and then you don't need to mess around with regex or string splitting etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.parse.aspx

PK  :-)

Comment: Well, now, that's just *too* easy! :)

Comment: I added System.Windows to reference and get error(no point.parse). Where can I find WindowsBase.dll? I am using vs2017 in VB in a windows form.

Comment: Do note the post is about 10 years old now! I would start with looking at the docs for whatever version and stack you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple string split using ',' as the delimiter, and then just use `int.parse(string)` to convert that to an int, and pass the ints into the Point constructor.

Comment: I agree - simple and easy to read too.

There's an old saying... "if you have a problem and you think you need to solve it with a regular expression... you now have two problems"

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq this could be a 1-liner

```
//assuming a list of strings like this
var strings = new List<String>{
   "13,2",
   "2,4"};

//get a list of points
var points = (from s in strings
             select new Point(s.split(",")[0], s.split(",")[1]))
             .ToList();

 // or Point.Parse as PK pointed out
var points = (from s in strings select Point.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

I'm using a mac to write this, so I can't check syntax, but that should be close.

Comment: fair enough, but if you get linq, that's not actually a bad one liner. and i should have said single statement, not 1 liner, i'd format as 3 lines like above.