# Parse PointF From String in C#?

Tags: c#, string, point

Well I have points saved to files that look like this:

```
PointF p = new PointF(109.1679, 162.4473);
string lineInFile = p.ToString();

// in file it looks like this then:
{X=109,1679, Y=162,4473}
```

Well I can't use linq nor .NET Framework 4.5 right now. I need a solution pure C# up to 4.0. So how would I parse the point ?

*Note that it's `PointF` not `Point` and the language specific formatting is making the dot appear as a comma in the string.*

---

**Edit:** I've accepted an answer but I wished the tiny problem with user modified files would be resolved too. Like `{ X = 109,1679   ,Y  =    162,4473  }`

Comment: Can you go for a json format?

Comment: Why can't you use LINQ?

Comment: @DanPantry: How does LINQ help to reverse `PointF.ToString`?

Comment: Not saying he does, I was just wondering why he felt the need to explicitly state he can't use it :P

Comment: @DanPantry: ive overlooked that he mentioned it. Well, LINQ is surely not the right tool to parse a string to `float` or `PointF`.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, @TimSchmelter :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter [I've seen this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718350/how-to-convert-a-string-into-a-point/2718364#2718364)

Comment: @mini-me: yes, but there LINQ is just used to parse multiple strings which you could replace easily with a loop (f.e. if you want to parse multiple lines in the file). So LINQ does not help to solve the core problem: how to get the `x` and `y` `floats` out of the `string` to create a `PointF`.

Comment: @mini-me: why do you think that the users will modify the file? If they can change it's content you cannot rely on any format, if you don't expect that they modify it you can ensure a strict format since `PointF.ToString` is implemented this way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because I had problems with bad user input already and had to service because of it. Just trying to build robust software that can ignore junk spaces and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a string method only version using `string.Split` and `float.TryParse`:

```
string[] tokens = lineInFile.Split(new[]{", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string valueX = tokens[0].Split('=')[1];
string valueY = tokens[1].Split('=')[1].TrimEnd('}');
float x; float y;
if (float.TryParse(valueX, out x) && float.TryParse(valueY, out y))
{
    PointF parsed = new PointF(x, y);
}
```

Note that it works only if the same `NumberDecimalSeparator` is used to parse the string to float as   used on `PointF.ToString`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use regular expressions to parse the format back again:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Match m = Regex.Match("{X=109,1679, Y=162,4473}", "{X=(\\d+.\\d+), Y=(\\d+.\\d+)}");
PointF p = new PointF(float.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value), float.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value));
```

Note that I used a `.` to check for the decimal separator as the output of `ToString()` will vary depending on locale.

I assume you can't change the file structure of your output file, otherwise you could just use the in-built functions for XML or JSON Serialization.

Comment: You could use `[.,]` to check for a decimal (instead of any character) and maybe do a replace "," into "." before parsing.

Comment: @HansKesting Hmm, are those the *only* decimal separators though? Anyway, any other character will correctly throw a parse exception.

Comment: This solution will adhere to CurrentCulture by using being relaxed about the regular expression used and using `float.Parse()` to parse the entire value using the current culture

Comment: @RGraham - I checked and was surprised to find cultures that use `/` (fa-IR), or (only for currencies) `-` (kk-KZ) or `\`` (mr-IN)